# Is the axiom of choice used here?

Tags: real-analysis, axiom-of-choice

I was reading the following
[How do i prove that every open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a union of at most countable open rectangles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271420/how-do-i-prove-that-every-open-set-in-mathbbr2-is-a-union-of-at-most-count)

The answer by "user4594" basically considers a k-cell with rational endpoints, and I am guessing that when he says that "E would be the union of these cells" the axiom of choice is needed because for each x there may be more than one k-cell with rational endpoints.

Am I correct?

Comment: One can choose the ball canonically (largest radius), and then choose the cell canonically.

Answer (score 2):

You could actually take all rectangles with rational endpoints containing $x$, since there are at most countably many of them, so you don't need choice.

Anyway, choice on subsets of a countable set is provable without the full Axion of Choice.

Comment: But, isn't the "index set", which in this case the set itself, uncountable?

Comment: No, you can well-order the set of all rectangles with rational coordinates. Then, for any $x$, you can take the least rectangle in that well-ordering that contains $x$, which is well-defined.In any event, you don't need to choose one, you can take all of the rational rectangles for each $x$. @Dejon

Comment: (I might have used the wrong term when I wrote countable choice - the Axiom of Countable Choice is not what I was referring to...)

Comment: Basically, $U$ is the union of all rational rectangles contained within it, and the set of those rectangles is countable.

Comment: Ah, well, at least I'm in good company with the random comment-less downvoter also hitting Asaf. Sigh

Comment: Good company is hard to find nowadays!

Answer (score 2):

Without the axiom of choice the rational numbers can be well-ordered, since they are countable. Therefore the set of $k$-rectangles with rational endpoints is countable.

So we don't need the axiom of choice to *really* choose from this collection.