# Why an open set in $R^n$ might not be written as countable union of disjoint open intervals?

Tags: real-analysis

There is a theorem saying that every open set in $R$ can be written as a countable union of **disjoint** open intervals. And we can also show any open set in $R^n$ can be written as the union of countable many bounded open intervals ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271420/how-do-i-prove-that-every-open-set-in-mathbbr2-is-a-union-of-at-most-count)).

I understand the proofs of the above two statements, but it feels strange that $R^n$ does not share the same property as $R$. Is there any explanation that why an open set in $R^n$ might not be written as countable union of disjoint open intervals?

Comment: What do you mean by open intervals in $\mathbb R^n$ when $n>1$?

Comment: FYI, a much better answer was given by Noah Schweber in response to a "duplicate" version of this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1900272/169852

Answer (score 3):

Yes. $\:$ For integers $n$ that are greater than $1\hspace{-0.02 in}$, $\mathbf{R}^n$'s usual topology is not an [order topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology).

Specifically, $\mathbf{R}^n$ will have no [cut points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-point), whereas *every* point of $\mathbf{R}$ is a cut point.

Answer (score 3):

$\Bbb R$ has many topological properties that $\Bbb R^2$, for example, doesn't share.  Another example is $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is not connected, while $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ is connencted.

Comment: Hi, sorry if it's a trivial question but I didn't really understand how connectedness plays the role. Can you please explain a bit more?